# NullPointerException PowerMock for class with both utility methods and Instance Methods

Tags: java, gradle, powermockito

```
gradleVersion = '4.1'
"org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.3"
testCompile("org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.3")
Jacoco default version used by Gradle 4.1
```

Null pointer Exception for class that has both Utility methods and Instance Methods.
I am trying to automate a class similar to it.

Class under test is:

```
public class StaticandInstance {
    public int age;
    public String name;
public static String commonPrefix(int age){
    if(age <18)
        return "Junior";
    if(age > 18 && age< 65)
        return "Mr/Miss/Mrs";
    if(age>=65)
        return "Senior";

    return "Sir/Madam";             
}
public StaticandInstance(int age,String name){
    this.age=age;
    this.name=name;
    }
public String callPerson(){
   return commonPrefix(age)+" " + name; 
    }
}
```

Test Class is

```
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;

    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
    import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
    import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest({StaticandInstance.class})
    public class StaticandInstanceTest {
        StaticandInstance instance;
        @Test
        public void testStaticAndInstance() {
            PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticandInstance.class);
            instance= new StaticandInstance(15,"Vikram");
            String test = instance.callPerson();
            assertEquals(test, "Junior Vikram");
        }

    }
```

When I execute this as JUnit It runs successfully but failed to run with Gradle and shows Jacoco Code Coverage as Zero.

Error Message is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at StaticandInstance.<init>(StaticandInstance.java:19)
    at testStaticAndInstance(StaticandInstanceTest.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

Comment: Why do you mock `commonPrefix()`? You do not need to mock it. You can run without it. 
`public class StaticandInstanceTest {
    StaticandInstance instance;
    @Test
    public void testStaticAndInstance() {
        instance= new StaticandInstance(15,"Vikram");
        String test = instance.callPerson();
        assertEquals(test, "Junior Vikram");
    }

}`

Comment: The logic inside the static method is complicated I just want to mock its behavior. It is passing in JUnit but not passing using PowerMockito

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your gradle file is OK and for the given example you provide. I think you forgot to specify what should happen when the static method `commonPrefix` is called with the parameter `15`.

Check the following code and the comments in code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({StaticandInstance.class})
public class StaticandInstanceTest {
    StaticandInstance instance;

    @Test
    public void testStaticAndInstance() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticandInstance.class);
        instance = new StaticandInstance(15, "Vikram");
        // You have to specify what happen when the static method you are trying to mock is called.
        Mockito.when(StaticandInstance.commonPrefix(15)).thenReturn("Junior");
        // Then you can do your actual method call
        String test = instance.callPerson();
        // And assert
        assertEquals(test, "Junior Vikram");
    }

}
```

But, for the specific case you provide, there is probably no need for PowerMockito and static mock at all.

```java
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class StaticandInstanceTest {
    StaticandInstance instance;

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        instance = new StaticandInstance(15, "Vikram");
        // Then you can do your actual method call
        String test = instance.callPerson();
        // And assert
        assertEquals(test, "Junior Vikram");
    }

}
```

Comment: I agree with your comments but I have to automate for a Company which has similar Structure but complicated logic. I need to mock the static methods which are inside a Class with Instance Methods that uses those static methods. It is Mix of both Utility and real Instances

Comment: Understood, then the line `Mockito.when(StaticandInstance.commonPrefix(15)).thenReturn("Junior");` doesn't work for you ? Maybe you could mention those requirements(and any other) in the question and in your code, so the restrictions will be clearer folks reading the question.

Comment: Ok, but the problem in the example still the same, you need to specify, what will happen when your mocked class gets called `StaticInstance#commonPrefix` with the parameter `15`, of course your logic could be more complicated here, but in general when using Mockito(PowerMock included) you need to specify this behaviour explicitly.